# Swift CoreData: NSFetchedResultsController with NSFetchRequestResult of type countResultType

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to get number of objects fetched by the fetch request using `NSFetchedResultsController` with `NSFetchRequestResult` of type `countResultType`

I implemented the fetch request, fetch request controller and two functions (1. to make initial fetch and 2. to listen to changes and report back)

function 1 runs without any errors and report correctly the number of fetched objects (no issues)
but function 2 whenever it is triggered to event of content change, the app crashes with the following error:
**Thread 1: "Result type of fetched object is not an NSManagedObjectIDResultType, NSDictionaryResultType or NSManagedObjectResultType."
**

I am not sure what wrong I have in my code, appreciate for help. thanks

the fetch request is as:

```
    var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
        fetchRequest = MessageEntity.fetchRequest()
        
        fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.countResultType
        
        let senderPredicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "senderUserId = %@", contactId
        )

        let recipientPredicate = NSPredicate(
            format: "recipientUserId = %@", contactId
        )
        
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
            orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
                senderPredicate,
                recipientPredicate
            ]
        )
        
        // Add Sort Descriptors
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        
        return fetchRequest
    }
```

fetch request controller is as:

```
    lazy var fetchResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
        fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.countResultType
        
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

and two functions:

1. to make the initial fetch
2. to listen to changes

function 1 to make initial fetch as:

```
    func loadMessagesFromCoreData() {
        print("loadMessagesFromCoreData: Thread is \(Thread.current) main? \(Thread.isMainThread)")
        
        Task { [weak self] in
            do {
                try self?.fetchResultsController.performFetch()

                guard let entities = self?.fetchResultsController.fetchedObjects
                else { throw AppAlert.error(error: "unable to load messages from core data") }
                print("receiving local messages on load \(String(describing: entities.last))")
            } catch {
                print("Error loading messages from core data:", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

function 2 to listen for changes as:

```
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {            
            guard let entities = controller.fetchedObjects
            else { return }
            print("receiving local messages on change \(String(describing: entities.last))")
    }
```

Comment: Where you are going wrong is trying to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` with `countResultType` - as the exception tells you, you can't do this.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don’t think so, because the type is already specified in the fetch request and the initial load of objects work perfectly fine returning the correct number of objects. The error only comes from the second function which listens to content changes. I want to use the countResultType in the load and the changes content.

Comment: You cannot. Change the type. It won't crash. Change the type back, it will crash. The exception message is clear. You can use `NSManagedObjectIDResultType` and access `fetchedObjects.count`

Comment: @Paulw11 then why it is working with the initial load? And doesn’t crash?

Comment: Because it probably doesn't check the result type until the change occurs and it goes to determine the changed objects. It can't do this with a count result type, so it crashes.

Comment: I don’t want to load the objects to control the memory usage. Loading the objects will consume lot of memory unnecessarily

Comment: I guess there is a solution

Comment: No, it won't. Core data uses faulting, so the full object isn't loaded until you access a property. Also, you can use `NSManagedObjectIDResultType` so it will just give you an array of object IDs. Don't pre-optimise. You are worrying about something that isn't actually a problem

Comment: Okay I will try with objectID as workaround so not to load the whole data and get the count

Comment: @Paulw11 but in this case what is the use of countResultType? Only to be used with initial load? Maybe!

Comment: You can use the `countResultType` with an `NSFetchRequest`, but you can't use it with a `NSFetchedResultController` because it can't compute the "delta" when there are changes in the `NSManagedContext`. Yes, a count result type will use less memory, but due to the way Core Data uses object faulting, it doesn't fetch the entire object into memory anyway.